# IndexError: tuple index out of range - first time making aa sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

**The problem**

(I had to delete and remake the question again beacause someone edited my question so weird that I couldn't edit it to get any help :(     )

I have been looking into this for hours and hours and can't even make 1 database at all. I have looked at tons of examples but all of them involve making the dictionary in the program. I need to find out how to take an already existing dictionary and turn it into a sqlite database.

I have tried so much but have not gotten close and I don't know where I can go to understand this concept. I have looked on stack overflow but every single question involving this has the dictionary made from scratch I need an example that shows the dictionary as a variable only.

I keep hitting random error after random error with no luck.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3
import json

tag = ''
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name))
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            tag_dict = tag.as_dict()
            #print(tag_dict)

            conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
            c = conn.cursor()

            for table in tag_dict.keys():
                c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table, initial_db))
                for k, v in tag_dict[table].items():
                    c.execute("ALTER TABLE {} \
                                ADD {} {}".format(table, k, v))

            c.close()
            conn.close()
```

Here is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "//VGMSTATION/testing scripts/search and print2.py", line 22, in c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table, initial_db)) NameError: name 'initial_db' is not defined
```

I tried taking out initial_db as I only got that code from here: how to create a sqlite3 table from a dictionary However I got this instead:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3
import json

tag = ''
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name))
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            tag_dict = tag.as_dict()
            #print(tag_dict)

            conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
            c = conn.cursor()

            for table in tag_dict.keys():
                c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table))
                for k, v in tag_dict[table].items():
                    c.execute("ALTER TABLE {} \
                                ADD {} {}".format(table, k, v))

            c.close()
            conn.close()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "//VGMSTATION/testing scripts/search and print2.py", line 22, in c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table)) IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Here is what tag_dict looks like:

```
{'comment': u"Shoot 'em up", 'album': u'Fortified Zone', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Main Theme', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'filesize': 135151220L, 'composer': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'year': u'1991', 'duration': 96.93016666666666, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u"Shoot 'em up", 'album': u'Fortified Zone', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Stage 2', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'filesize': 112873545L, 'composer': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'year': u'1991', 'duration': 83.95053333333334, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u"Shoot 'em up", 'album': u'Fortified Zone', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'Track 3', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': u'8-Bit', 'albumartist': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'filesize': 134273566L, 'composer': u'Tsukasa Tawada', 'year': u'1991', 'duration': 95.96253333333334, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
```

I understand there are multiple questions like this but again, I haven't found any single question that shows the dictionary as a variable that I can put into this sqlite code.

Also I haven't found a single example of the most basic way to create a table in sqlite using an already created dictionary variable.

Any ideas or links to point me in the right direction would be AWESOME! lol

Thank you for your time,

Comment: What tables fo you want to create? What columns should they have? What exactly is tag.as_dict() giving you?

Comment: @norie - was able to delete the question's data and rewrite it from scratch so I can show you the data from `tag_dict`

Comment: I think you need to separate things out here.

First you need to create the database and it's tables, and then you use the data from tag_dict to populate the tables in the database.

I don't have any links to share right now but I'm going to take your code and see what I can do with it. P..S. What tables/fields do you want in the database?

Comment: @norie - From looking at the dict, I think I will need `title` `album` `comment` `genre` `artist` `composer` and `year`. However any sets of fields for an example is fine with me. I am just grateful for any response. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite simplified example of how to do this.

It only creates one table - **tracks**.

The field names/data types are hard-coded - **'title', 'album', 'comment', 'genre', 'artist', 'composer', 'year'**, all **TEXT** fields

Also, it only inserts data for the MP3 files in the current directory.

```
import glob
from tinytag import TinyTag
import sqlite3

def create_table(con, table_name, fields):

  field_info = ','.join([ f'{field} TEXT' for field in fields])
  sql = f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({field_info})'

  cur = con.cursor()

  cur.execute(sql)

  cur.close()

def insert_track(con, table_name, track_data):
  sql = f'INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
  cur = con.cursor()

  cur.execute(sql, track_data)

  conn.commit()

conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')

create_table(conn, 'tracks', ['title', 'album', 'comment', 'genre', 'artist', 'composer', 'year'])

files = glob.glob('*.mp3')

data = [TinyTag.get(file).as_dict() for file in files]

for track in data:
  insert_track(conn, 'tracks', (track['title'], track['album'], track['comment'], track['genre'], track['artist'], track['composer'], track['year']))

conn.close()
```